# How do I parse my JSON array row by row

Tags: php, mysql, json

These are my JSON list that currently I retrieved from my database.

> {"0":"1","id":"1","1":"2015-01-11
>   12:30:45","DateTimeCreated":"2015-01-11 12:30:45","2":"Pending
>   Confirmation","status_desc":"Pending
>   Confirmation","3":"benjiwjh","username":"benjiwjh"}{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"2015-02-11
>   09:09:09","DateTimeCreated":"2015-02-11 09:09:09","2":"Pending
>   Confirmation","status_desc":"Pending
>   Confirmation","3":"LSH","username":"LSH"}{"0":"7","id":"7","1":"2015-12-03
>   18:30:00","DateTimeCreated":"2015-12-03
>   18:30:00","2":"Unresolved","status_desc":"Unresolved","3":"SWJH","username":"SWJH"}{"0":"12","id":"12","1":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","DateTimeCreated":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","2":"Resolved","status_desc":"Resolved","3":"benjiwjh","username":"benjiwjh"}{"0":"14","id":"14","1":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","DateTimeCreated":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","2":"Resolved","status_desc":"Resolved","3":"CYJM","username":"CYJM"}{"0":"15","id":"15","1":"2015-11-12
>   12:11:10","DateTimeCreated":"2015-11-12
>   12:11:10","2":"Unresolved","status_desc":"Unresolved","3":"LSH","username":"LSH"}

I would like to show it row by row like:

> {"0":"1","id":"1","1":"2015-01-11
>   12:30:45","DateTimeCreated":"2015-01-11 12:30:45","2":"Pending
>   Confirmation","status_desc":"Pending
>   Confirmation","3":"benjiwjh","username":"benjiwjh"}
>
> {"0":"4","id":"4","1":"2015-02-11
>   09:09:09","DateTimeCreated":"2015-02-11 09:09:09","2":"Pending
>   Confirmation","status_desc":"Pending
>   Confirmation","3":"LSH","username":"LSH"}
>
> {"0":"7","id":"7","1":"2015-12-03
>   18:30:00","DateTimeCreated":"2015-12-03
>   18:30:00","2":"Unresolved","status_desc":"Unresolved","3":"SWJH","username":"SWJH"}
>
> {"0":"12","id":"12","1":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","DateTimeCreated":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","2":"Resolved","status_desc":"Resolved","3":"benjiwjh","username":"benjiwjh"}
>
> {"0":"14","id":"14","1":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","DateTimeCreated":"2014-12-03
>   12:10:30","2":"Resolved","status_desc":"Resolved","3":"CYJM","username":"CYJM"}
>
> {"0":"15","id":"15","1":"2015-11-12
>   12:11:10","DateTimeCreated":"2015-11-12
>   12:11:10","2":"Unresolved","status_desc":"Unresolved","3":"LSH","username":"LSH"}

And not like the whole chunk stuck together. Should I be using a loop when I'm retrieving the data? For now this is how I retrieve my data:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: What's wrong with your approach doing it in a loop and parse it object by object ? Sounds like it's exactly what you want , isn't it ;) ?

Comment: I mean like i don't know how to do it. Like in code wise - andre classen

Comment: Are you just wanting an extra blank line between each `$row` printed in `echo json_encode($row);`?

Comment: Yup. Because each row is a different data but in a same table (in the database) @JeffBridgman

Comment: One note, if you are using the resulting overall blob as one response, it's not valid. You'd need a comma between each `{ .. }`, and wrap the whole thing in an array: `[ .. ]`. The above would be rejected by many/most JSON deserializers.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing these JSON objects one after another like this means that the full output of your PHP script will not be valid JSON. If you build an array of arrays as you fetch results from your database, you can `json_encode` once at the end to produce an array of JSON objects.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Then you should be able to iterate over the resulting array as I believe you are attempting to do with whatever is using the output of this PHP script.

Comment: So how should i write it?
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[] = . $row['id'] . + .$row['DateTimeCreated'] . + .$row['status_desc']. + .$row['username']
}
echo json_encode($output); - like that?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm bad with codes so i don't really know where should i be adding my stuffs in. Please do help, thank you.

Comment: Well, I thought the way I wrote it in the answer should work. It really just depends on what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_fetch_all`

```
echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```